# How to perform HSEsol in VASP calculations?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, magnetism, hse06

I want to perform `HSEsol (PBEsol + HSE06)` calculation on a material (***monolayer***) that doesn't have experimental data available. Could you please tell me how to implement this in the `INCAR` file for relaxation purposes ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the following flags in your INCAR to specify HSEsol:

```
GGA = PS
LHFCALC = .TRUE.
HFSCREEN = 0.2
```

I also recommend setting `Algo = All` for smoother SCF convergence. The VASP manual [suggests](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/LASPH) setting `LASPH=.TRUE.` as well for hybrid calculations, but that's a decision for you to make.

In the future, if you are ever curious about how to define a given density functional, you can check out all the pre-defined recipes in the [Atomic Simulation Environment](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/). The example for HSEsol is [here](https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/blob/master/ase/calculators/vasp/create_input.py#L891).

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew, that's a good advice. Can I find there also a guide on how to determine the U parameter for GGA+U calculation using VASP ?

Comment: Since that's a separate question, I recommend opening a new question about GGA+U calculations (after checking that someone hasn't already done so). For instance, your question may already be answered here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/109/what-is-the-appropriate-way-of-determining-a-value-for-the-hubbard-like-potentia/

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but that's with QE and I want to use VASP with linear response method.

Comment: @ChiKou Have you checked out the tutorial on VASP's webpage? https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Calculate_U_for_LSDA%2BU
Usually these are easy to follow.